# iPhone - Wrong Localization after Changing the Language

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization

I am developing an application that supports English and Arabic localization. If the iPhone language is set to Arabic, everything is fine. If I changed the language to English, the app continues to change in Arabic.

I tried the following:

1. Terminating the application before changing the language.
2. Removing the application from iPhone. Changed Language to English. Restarting the iPhone. And building the application from scratch (still in Arabic!).
3. I tried cleaning using shift-command-k (also failed).
4. I removed the application. restarted the phone. Cleaned the build folder (shift-option-command-k). Then I built the application, and guess what, it's still in Arabic! (How, in God's name, did the iPhone know that I used Arabic before?! I restarted the phone many times!, removed and clean the build directory!).

So, what do you think I should do?

Note: other apps that provide localization are working fine.

Comment: Does the project have `en.lproj` `Localizable.strings` file?

Comment: @fannheyward Thank you so much. That fixed it. Could you write your comment as an answer so I can check it as an "answer". Also, this arises another question, if I want the application to be in arabic only, then I should consider a single localizable.strings file (no en.lproj)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the project have `en.lproj` `Localizable.strings` file?

Thanks @Shatou Dev ,I make my comment as an answer.